# Random variables in finite sample spaces.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

In the context of finite sample spaces consider using random variables in this way: We have an experiment modeled by a given probability distribution and we are interested in another experiment, one step of which may be represented by the first. Now using a random variable can help us in deducing the probability space modeling the second experiment.

For example,

- Suppose we know the probability distribution corresponding to the experiment of drawing $N$ balls from an urn containing $n$ white and $n$ black balls. This is our first experiment. We have a **measure space** modeling it.
- Suppose our second experiment was drawing the $N$ balls and then counting the white balls. At this point we don't know the probability distribution of the second distribution. We have a **measurable space** modeling it.

We define a random variable $X$ as a function from the sample space of the first experiment to the real numbers such that $X(\omega)$ is the count of the number of white balls.

The probability distribution induced by $X$ models the second experiment; i.e. the one which consists of drawing the $N$ balls and counting the white ones. In this way the second experiment was modeled conveniently and we have a ready made distribution for it (push forward). So the advantage of using random variables is that it helped us in determining the new probability space using the old space.

I think in the context of finite sample spaces this is a way in which random variables can be really useful.  Is this mode of reasoning correct?

In the context of continuous distributions [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure) says that:

> Many natural probability distributions, such as the chi distribution, can be obtained via this construction.

My question is in the specific context of finite sample spaces. Is this useful in this context?

Comment: The sample space of a probability system is composed of outcomes $\omega$. Each outcome tells us all info that we want to know about “what happened.” If the system involves multiple rounds of some experiment or sub-experiment, then the outcome $\omega$ must  be descriptive enough to tell us about all of those rounds. If it is not, we should redefine the sample space. Random variables $X(\omega)$ are always defined as functions of a (full) outcome $\omega$.

Comment: In this context, there are two experiments: The first is related to the second but is not necessarily a "round" of the second. We know the probability distribution of the first and use it to find that of the second.

Comment: No. If you have two experiments then $\omega$ should specify what happened for both. So $X(\omega)$ can be the number of balls on experiment 1 and $Y(\omega)$ the number of white ones on experiment 2 , all functions of the same outcome $\omega$.

Comment: I am not sure you understand. The first experiment is merely drawing the balls and not doing anything else. Consider the outcome $\omega$ as a sequence in this context. For example, if $N=3$ then $\omega=(W,B,B)$. Let the set of all such outcomes  be $\Omega$. Here $\Omega$ is a set of finite sequences of W and B. The second experiment is drawing the balls and also counting the white ones. For the second experiment an arbitrary outcome is the count of the white balls thus drawn. The set of outcomes is $\Omega'=\{0,1,\cdots n\}$.

Comment: (Continued)My point is that the function $X:\Omega\to\Omega'$ automatically yields the probability distribution for the second experiment using the probability distribution of the first. My question is whether this is a useful way?

Comment: No. If you define a sample space then you must also specify a distribution on that space. The ball/bin problem typically uses the natural distribution where all outcomes are equally likely. And the outcomes for that already allow a random variable $X$ being the number of white balls. In your second experiment you have a new sample space but there is no distribution specified. If the distribution is equally likely over all outcomes of the new space then it does NOT coincide with a distribution for $X$. On the other hand if you want the distribution to be the same as $X$ then, fine, but so what?

Comment: See the updated question.

Comment: You clearly feel this is useful. Indeed random variables used in different problems can have the same distribution even if they are functions defined on different sample spaces. This is also why things like $E[X], Var(X),P[X>2]$ can be computed knowing only the distribution (not the sample space) and are useful in many problems with different sample spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Both experiments can be modeled using the same underlying probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathsf{P})$, where $\Omega=\{W,B\}^{n}$, $\mathcal{F}=2^{\Omega}$, and $\mathsf{P}$ depending on the way those balls are drawn (with or without replacement). Now you can construct random variables representing different measurements. For example,
$$
X(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{\omega_i=W\},
$$
or
$$
Y(\omega)=\min\{i:\omega_i=B\}
$$
Each random variable then induces a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. $P_X(\,\cdot\,)=\mathsf{P}(X^{-1}(\,\cdot\,))$ and $P_Y(\,\cdot\,)=\mathsf{P}(Y^{-1}(\,\cdot\,))$. Using these distributions (push-forward measures) one may directly determine the distributions of certain transformations of $X$ and $Y$. For example, if $Z=X^2$, then
$$
P_Z((-\infty,z])=P_X((-\infty,\sqrt{z}]).
$$

So in many cases one doesn't need to explicitly construct a probability space. It suffices to specify the distribution of random variables at hand (see this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3358503/continuous-measure-theoretic-probability-concrete-example/3358556#3358556) for details).